# Convert IF to TOGGLE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code but it works with scroll height, i want to do something different.  I want to convert it to Toggle, is it possible? First click add .animated and remove .fix, on second click remove .animated and add .fix.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll > 20) {
        $header.addClass('animated').removeClass('fix');
    } else {
        $header.removeClass('animated').addClass('fix');
    }

});
```

I'm new on javascript can anyone help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `toggleClass`? It accepts a _switch_ parameter.

Comment: Yes but I have no idea how can i use it

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-className-switch)?

Comment: $( ".header" ).click(function() {
  $( '.header' ).toggleClass( "animated" );
});

This is what i've tried, but it makes no sense because i need remove class .fix

Answer (score 1):

The `toggleClass` accepts a *switch* argument, a Boolean value. `true` adds the className and `false` removes the className.

```
var bool = scroll > 20;
$header.toggleClass('animated', bool).toggleClass('fix', !bool);
```

Comment: I need to do it when i click a #div. How can i do that?

Comment: @BerkKaya Use the `toggleClass` in your click handler?

Comment: I didn't understand clearly, i made css animation and I'm triggering it with your code when scrolltop bigger than 20, but I want to disable scrolltop function and make new button. When i click button just trigger the animation. Second click remove animation.

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution like this, maybe somebody uses it.

```
$('.header').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.header').toggleClass("animated") .removeClass('fix');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```